# Solr score diff in doc list and Explain score

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, solr8

I am getting a list of docs when hitting my solr query. Strange issue I am facing is that when I am trying to explain the score calculation for a document then the score is coming different in what is shown in the doc list.

Example: score for a doc in the

```
"docs": [{
    "id": "1DMOXQ3VN7FF",
    "score": 6.7063313
},
{
    "id": "6WNYN6NVVPDU",
    "score": 6.699659
}]
```

Now the score for the doc in id when I try to explain it

```
 "6WNYN6NVVPDU": {
                "match": true,
                "value": 10.562147,
                "description": <some score calc logic here> 
}
```

You can see two scores for the same doc. I have never seen this earlier in solr. What is the possible explanation here. Thank!

Comment: I found a similar question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921106/how-and-why-do-solr-explain-values-differ-from-the-solr-score?rq=2 
But looks like lucene bug is fixed.